# Typo3 linux server error: Could not load layout file

Tags: linux, typo3

After I uploaded my Typo3-Website onto a linux server and tryed to call the homepage, I get the error: "Could not load layout file. Tried following paths: "/Main.html", "/Main" "
I checked the correct spelling (uppercase) of my layout file: It seems to be correct and in the right place. Any ideas?

Comment: In case you uploaded from a case insensitive FS (like MAC OS) to a linux server, check if there are differences in the spelling (in regards of case sensitivity) of folders and files between the configuration (TS) and the FS.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot. I have checked the file paths and noticed I had to delete the two slashes after the equal signs.

This works on a windows platform:

```
partialRootPath = /fileadmin/Private/Partials/
layoutRootPath = /fileadmin/Private/Layouts
```

But on a linux server it has to look this way:

```
partialRootPath = fileadmin/Private/Partials/
layoutRootPath = fileadmin/Private/Layouts
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using TYPO3 before 7 and the `StandaloneView`. In this case, identify in your code where you use this view and check the calls to `setTemplatePathAndFilename` or the `templateRootPath`. You are probably having an issue with the root path being set to something that does not exist.

This might be a situation of incompatible cAsiNg of the directory name. This is especially possible if you are testing locally on MacOS (case insensitive) and then uploading to Linux (case sensitive).

If this does not help, please provide us with more information about your scenario (code, settings, environment where it works, etc).